# Restoring mongorestore to cosmosDB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I try to restore a mongoDB Collection to CosmosDB and the Performance is very bad. It's a 8GB dump (with 8Million datasets) and after 2 hours only 500MB are restored.
The Collection is set to 20.000 RU, even with 100000 the Performance is still bad.

Do you have any idea?

Everything else (except the Collection with RU Settings) has default settings)
I am uploading from a Server in Germany to western europe Region. From the same Server i did Uploads to different mongoDB Services with the same data in about 2 hours with indexing enabled.

[image: Dashboard2]

[image: Dashboard]

Comment: Not really much provided in your question. What do these documents look like? How large are the documents? Where are you pushing the data from: local machine? vm in same region? vm in different region? How is your indexing configured: did you set to lazy indexing? Have you looked at the portal's dashboard for your database to see what its RU usage and throttling is? Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Hello David, thanks for your reply. I changed the article as you described. It was critism and about user expectations. A rant would imply a rude description about the product. I never said that the product is .... Please keep the discussion on a honest level.

Comment: Hello @Dominic did you find a solution for this? I have a 200gb mongodb and thinking about moving to cosmos DB or not

I already have problems when i'm trying to import my test database (which is 631MB) I created another issue about these errors on here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47884300/mongorestore-error-creating-indexes-on-cosmos-db

Comment: Hi. @hardc0der Did you suceed with your import. I think at that time the generation of the indeces could be part of the problem.

Comment: Hello @DominicBöttger i gave up to use cosmosDB :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough StackOverflow points to add a comment, so I'm replying as an answer. First, can you check the Portal metrics to see if you are receiving any throttled requests? If this is 0 or a low number, then it's safe to say that our bottleneck is somewhere else. Second, how many insertion workers are you using for your import? We will need to set this to a high enough number to saturate the entire throughput.